# Why is solid sodium hydride a base and not an acid when reacted with water?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, electronegativity

When solid $\ce{NaH}$ is mixed with water, the products are not $\ce{Na-}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$. The reaction yields $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{H2}$ gas.

Why does solid $\ce{NaH}$ not act as a Brønsted acid in this case?

Comment: It's actually one of strongest bases...

Comment: @Mithoron Of course, since it produces the very strong base NaOH.

Answer (score 9):

The answer lies in electronegativity. Sodium has a significantly lower electronegativity ($\approx 1.0$) than hydrogen ($\approx 2.1$) meaning that hydrogen pulls electron density towards itself, away from sodium to generate a sodium cation and a hydride anion.

For a compound to be a Brønsted acid, you need to draw electron density *away* from the hydrogen, i.e. connect it to an electronegative atom such as oxygen, fluorine, nitrogen etc. Only then can it formally be described as $\ce{H+}$ and can dissociate as such.

A hydride is much better described as $\ce{H-}$ and has a free lone pair. As such, it is a Brønsted *base*, not an acid. In fact, if you extend the Brønsted acid/base definition in the way Lewis did, you will arrive at the sodium ($\ce{Na+}$) being the acidic species here.

The Brønsted acid/base reaction product of the base $\ce{H-}$ and the acid $\ce{H+}$ happens to be $\ce{H2}$, and because the acidic hydrogen is abstracted directly from water (hydrogen gas can bubble away, shifting the equilibrium even if the reaction were not thermodynamically favoured), $\ce{OH-}$ ions are left which can be written with the remaining $\ce{Na+}$ cation to give sodium hydroxide.

Answer (score 2):

The hydrogen is in the form of a $\ce{H^-}$ ion, negatively charged instead of the usual partial positive. Ths hydride ion strips a $\ce{H^+}$ from a $\ce{H_2O}$ molecule to become $\ce{H_2}$ gas and leaves behind $\ce{OH^-}$.

Comment: While it's correct, I think you should elaborate to provide better answer.